# Делегирование протокола

Tags: ios, swift

Всем привет! Только начал работать с протоколами, поэтому появился вот такой вопрос.

Есть два ViewController'a. С первого нужно передать данные на второй без помощи segue. Я создаю свой протокол

```
protocol MainTableViewControllerDelegate {  
func workerInfo(worker: Worker)  
}
```

Потом в этом же VC указываю следующее:

```
var delegate: MainTableViewControllerDelegate?
```

Отправляю данные:

```
let addTask = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Добавить задачу") { (action, indexPath) in  


// Отправление данных на AddTaskViewController  

        let sendWorker = self.workerArray[indexPath.row]  
        self.delegate?.workerInfo(worker: sendWorker)  
        print("Отправил \(sendWorker.fullName!)")  
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "addTaskVC")  
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)  
}
```

Во втором VC подписываюсь под протокол и реализую его метод:

```
func workerInfo(worker: Worker) {  
    self.aWorker = worker  
}
```

В итоге с первого VC данные передаются, а на второй в переменную aWorker приходит nil :(
Что я делаю не так?:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Привет! Не особо понятен вопрос, отвечу на то как понял.
Есть 2 контроллера А и B, если мне нужно передать некоторые данные из А в B - например по нажатии на ячейку, это можно сделать добавив в контроллере B переменную:

```
   class B { //addTaskVC
      var worker: Worker?
   }
```

И вот здесь где:

```
    let addTask = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Добавить задачу") { (action, indexPath) in 
        let sendWorker = self.workerArray[indexPath.row]  
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "addTaskVC")  
        vc.worker = sendWorker // мы устанавливаем значение этой переменной 
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)  
    }
```

В обратную сторону: из В в А - здесь да, как вариант можно использовать делегирование.
Для этого в В нужно добавить делегат:

```
   class B { //addTaskVC
      var worker: Worker?
      weak var delegate: MainTableViewControllerDelegate?
   }
```

И его уже нужно будет реализовать в контроллере А.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Все получилось!:)
Сам не знаю зачем столько всего намудрил, а оказалось все проще простого.

Answer (score 1):

А чем не устраивает segue и зачем все усложнять?

Если все же так хочется - нужно правильно понять это дело. К тому же, в таком сценарии незачем протоколы использовать.

Просто укажи

```
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "addTaskVC") as! Secondvc  
vc.aWorker = sendWorker
```

Comment: Именно это мне и нужно было. Все дело в том, что необходимо было сделать переход от rowAction, а я не знаю, можно ли это реализовать с помощью сегвея (думаю нет). Погуглил и наткнулся на делегирование, а оказалось все проще. Спасибо за помощь и за совет! :)